# Issue with orQueryWithSubqueries queries when also using nearGeoPoint:withinMailes

Tags: parse-platform

I am using PFQuery:orQueryWithSubqueries with several subqueries successfully. I am also using PFQuery:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles successfully as well.

But when I try to use PFQuery:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles as a subquery to a PFQuery:orQueryWithSubqueries the results do not appear to be respects the distance criteria.

Has anyone else seen anything like this combination returning the wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success sometimes by a applying the nearGeoPoint: to the or query itself, instead of to the subqueries. If that makes sense in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not applicable in the case of the query that I am using.